# How can I save the amount of steps taken in a day to the firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to retrieve the midday `12:00`. This going to be used for the pedometer in core motion.

```
 func updateStepcountLabel (startDate :Date){
       pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: startDate, to: Date()) {
            [weak self] pedometerData, error in
      if let error = error {
           print(error)
        } else if let pedometerData = pedometerData {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self?.stepLabel
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

this method allows the user to count their steps. What I want to do is when the time reaches `00:00:00`, I want to reset the step counter to `0`  and then save the value at the time `11:59:00` pm to the firebase database.

method to save it on the Firebase database

var ref: DatabaseReference! ref = Database.database().reference() let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid let key = ref.child("user").child(user) ref.child("user/(user)/pedometer").setValue(self.stepLabel)

Thanks

Comment: The code you are showing looks to be only the code to get the steps.  Show the code where you are attempt to save the data to firebase and incited the issue you think you are having.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Firebase Getting Started Guide [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write)? It covers how to do this task.

Comment: This my function to save into the database

Comment: var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let key = ref.child("user").child(user)
    ref.child("user/\(user)/pedometer").setValue(self.stepLabel)